# How to prevent ScrollBar from scrolling up in FlowLayoutPanel

Tags: c#, winforms

I've been messing around with making a messager using C# and PHP. Now I'm using a flow layout panel to show my messages using a custom user control.

When I update the messages I simply clear the controls and put them in again. Just simple.

The problem is that everytime the controls are getting cleared my scrollbar goes up. I don't want that. I want the scrollbar to stay at where it is. I know It's not possible with just using the scrollbar but how could I update my controls without clearing the list?

Comment: Why are you clearing out all the controls every time?  The scrollbar is a reflection of where you are with respect to the contents.  If you clear out the container, why would the scroll bar stay at the bottom?...the bottom of what?...it's empty now.

Comment: I clear the controls because I don't want double occurences of the messages

Comment: You need a better algorithm to only add "messages" that are new.  Clearing and re-adding is a hack.  Clearing, btw, does not Dispose of the controls.

Comment: Agreed...fix the logic or change your protocol so you know if you've already received a message.